# Generate/create a random list of positive and negative floating numbers

Tags: python

I would like to create a random list of positive and negative floating numbers within a range
Like this:

0.1, 1.5, 0.6, -1.3, -0.4 and so on.

I know we have something of the likes of:

```
import random    
my_randoms = random.sample(xrange(100), 10)
```

But this seems to get me the floating and negative part of the list.

Thank very much, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by random and alternate?

Comment: like in the example, I want + and - values,

Comment: I added an edit to my answer to include digit precision to 1 to match your expectation from your example https://stackoverflow.com/a/55020984/3564632

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For random `float` numbers both `positive` and `negative` with a precision of 1 you can use:

```
import numpy as np    

size = 10
np.set_printoptions(precision=1)
my_randoms = np.random.uniform(-100, 100, size)
print(my_randoms)
```

It prints for example this:

```
[ 49.5  -2.  -54.5 -87.6  17.3  92.3  -1.4  47.7 -27.4 -31.8]
```

Comment: I prefered the solution importing random (without numpy) before the edit. why using numpy for such simple tasks? EDIT: just checked the random doc: python's random.uniform function does not allow to provide a size. but it can be done with a list comprehension.

Comment: @Tryph Sorry for the confusion numpty also have the size but I guess random.uniform doesn't have it?

Comment: Your answer seems to produce an error. Moreover, it doesn't generate alternate positive negative numbers.

Comment: @skaul05 I was editing it but the version with numpy is the answer i wanted to give

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
[random.randint(-10, 10) for i in xrange(10)]
```

Comment: This is for integers. I guess looking at the question example the author intended to generate float numbers

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seems here random.uniform() should be use but with certain number of decimal places.

Comment: I just added the precision to set the exact number of decimal you would like https://stackoverflow.com/a/55020984/3564632

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Try this one

`import random
 for x in range(10):
    print random.randint(100)`